# CMS Controlled Android Application?

Tags: java, android

Is this possible? creating an application that a person can add details or announcement via CMS?

Comment: By CMS do you mean a content management system?

Comment: yes, they will change/add somethings on the running android app

Answer (score 1):

In case your CMS is exposing the webservices, you can consume the XML/JSON responses you get from the server on your application and show the relevant data(details.announcements in your case).

Comment: that's what i thought but it also means i will request that service everytime, so i need a service for those?

Comment: i also think C2DMF is the answer for all of these?

Comment: i don't think so. can you provide a link that say so?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at our [JSON-based StorageRoom CMS](http://storageroomapp.com), we built it exactly for this use case.